# Help me understand Encryptpad and 7-zip for encryption

Tags: encryption, aes, gnupg, openpgp, veracrypt

I was looking to encrypt some text files (containing sensitive data) so I could safely keep them online (e.g. Google drive).

I have found three options:

1. 7-zip, which does AES-256
2. Encryptpad, which use OpenPGP symmetric encryption with AES
3. Microsoft Word with password protection, which uses AES as well.

(4. Veracrypt container is another option).

Help me understand what the comparative advantages and disadvantages of each system are?

Comment: Though this isn't an answer, I'd say for secure online storage, probably the option with OpenPGP.

Comment: You can also use gnupg directly...